# Difference between kinetic energy and force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics

I hope I don't make myself look stupid asking this question. Please note I'm relatively new to physics but am extremely interested. To test myself, I made up a time, velocity, and mass and filled in the rest. This is what followed:

```
v=9 m/s,
d=108 m,
t=12 s,
a=0.75 m/s/s,
M=7 kg,
p=63 kg m/s,
F=5.25 N,
W=756 J,
P=63 W,
KE=283.5 N
```

Is this correct? My question is what the difference is between the force and the kinetic energy. I was imagining something being thrown down a road, so shouldn't the force be the same as the kinetic energy? Am I being extremely stupid?

Comment: You need to draw conclusions based on physics reasoning, not common sense.  We use words that are commonly used in everyday language, but  mean very different things from their everyday meaning.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [What is the relationship between Force and Kinetic Energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122229).

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, energy and momentum will change if there's an applied force acting over a distance, even if the force is constant.

The difference between kinetic energy and force may become more clear if you consider the difference between what's happening *right now*, versus *over time*.

Taking the force you've given, you are right, for the mass $7 kg$, the acceleration is $.75 \frac{m}{s^2}$ (since, by Newton's 2nd law, $force=mass*acceleration$), but if there is an acceleration, the velocity will change as long as you maintain the applied force. Therefore, the speed you've given is a *right now* quantity, not what it will be in the future. Similarly, since the momentum is just $momentum=mass*velocity$, the momentum you've given is a *right now* quantity. And finally, since the speed increases when you maintain an applied force, the kinetic energy will increase, so it also is a *right now* quantity, rather than a constant.

It looks like you actually knew this to be true since you found that, when starting from rest (with zero momentum and zero kinetic energy since the velocity is zero), a mass which has a final velocity of $9 \frac{m}{s}$ after accelerating for $12 s$ must have had an applied force of $5.25 N$ since force is just the change in momentum over time, or

$F=\frac{m_{final}*v_{final}-m_{initial}*v_{initial}}{t}=\frac{7 kg* 9 \frac{m}{s}-7 kg* 0 \frac{m}{s}}{12 s}=5.25 N$

Notice that the force stayed the same, while the momentum and kinetic energy increase due to the force adding energy to the mass.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Try the following: 1) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 3) If you have a good question, ask it! Just search for duplicates and follow the [help center rules](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). 5) To format text see [the help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: *"Long story short, energy [...] will change if there's an applied force"* This is stated much too broadly: there are several ways for it to be untrue. Likewise *"but if there is an acceleration, the speed will change as long as you maintain the applied force"*. In particular the case of uniform circular motion has a net applied force and a non-zero acceleration at all times but the speed (and consequently kinetic energy) does not change.